# While-Loop to generate a sample

Tags: r, while-loop

Hellou

I've had problems with the following while loop in R. I try to know with what number of samples (n), I can achieve a variance less than 0.01 (dtest) and that let me to know the values of n, m, s and d:

```
n <- 100
x <- rnorm(n,0,1)
sd(x)
d <- sd(x)/sqrt(n)
dtest <- 0.01

while(dtest <=0.01) {
  x <- rnorm(n,0,1)
  n <- n+1
  m <- mean(x)
  s <- sd(x)
  d <- s/sqrt(n)
  return(output <- data.frame(n,m,s,d))
}
```

The first time I did the cycle without problems and it marked a n of approx 27K. Now only every time I execute the loop it accumulates

Comment: If seems to me that your code makes no sense.  In the while loop the dtest check is initially TRUE but it is not updated inside the while loop.  So it will loop forever.  And note that the return statement is used inside a function when it is exited, not a loop.  Suggest, you clarify your intent and update your question.  Good luck.

Comment: This looks like it's within a `function`, in which case the `return` is breaking out of the `while` loop after the first pass regardless of any updating of `dtest`. Note that `return` does not pair with `while`, it works from within `function`s only.

Comment: I wondered whether what you are doing this for is a power calculation: `library(pwr)
pwr.t.test(d = 0.01, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.80, type = "one. Sample")`

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues:

1. Your condition should compare `d` to `dtest`. Currently, it’s comparing two values that aren’t changed within the loop, so will run forever.
2. Increment `n` at the start of the loop. Otherwise you’re using a different `n` to compute `x` and `d`.
3. Just create your results dataframe once, after the loop, rather than creating and discarding with each loop. And don’t use `return()`, which is meant for use inside functions.
4. Note that `sd(x)/sqrt(n)` is standard error, not variance. Variance would be `sd(x)^2`.

```
set.seed(13)

n <- 99
x <- rnorm(n,0,1)
d <- sd(x)/sqrt(n)
dtest <- 0.01

while(dtest <= d) {
  n <- n+1
  x <- rnorm(n,0,1)
  s <- sd(x)
  d <- s/sqrt(n)
}
output <- data.frame(n,m = mean(x),s,d)
output
```

```
    n          m         s           d
1 9700 0.01906923 0.9848469 0.009999605
```